# 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.' using Parallel.For and a WritableBitmap

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm facing something I don't understand, and maybe someone can give me an understandable answer to this. I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see it.

I'm trying to load a Bitmap and set an Array of all pixels in it to process a blur method on it. I get an exception after calling this same method on different Bitmap multiple times.

To be clear, I have a combobox with items and following the items the background change with the same method. If I select all the items one by one, after a short time it throws the exception.

Here is the code:

```cs
private readonly ParallelOptions _pOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 };

        public void CreateFrom(string filePath)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public unsafe void CreateFrom(IBitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var writeableBitmap = WriteableBitmap.Decode(memoryStream);
                using var lockedBitmap = writeableBitmap.Lock();

                int* bmpPtr = (int*)lockedBitmap.Address;
                _width = writeableBitmap.PixelSize.Width;
                _height = writeableBitmap.PixelSize.Height;
                _dpi = writeableBitmap.Dpi;

                _alpha = new int[_width * _height];
                _red = new int[_width * _height];
                _green = new int[_width * _height];
                _blue = new int[_width * _height];

                Parallel.For(0, _width * _height, _pOptions, (i, parallelLoopState) =>
                {
                    _alpha[i] = (int)((*(bmpPtr + i) & 0xff000000) >> 24);
                    _red[i] = (*(bmpPtr + i) & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                    _green[i] = (*(bmpPtr + i) & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                    _blue[i] = *(bmpPtr + i) & 0x0000ff;
                });
            }
        }
```

After a few selection, it throws this exception at that line `_alpha[i] = (int)((*(bmpPtr + i) & 0xff000000) >> 24);`

If anyone can see why, that will be great ! TIA

Edit: Here is a short testing video, it's clearer than a thousand words lol
[Short demo](https://youtu.be/eF_UAMvXb7U)

Edit more: Here is the full class I made, thanks to all of them for this, it's really fast.

```cs
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.Shapes;
using Avalonia.Media.Imaging;
using Avalonia.Platform;
using Ready2Play.BitmapFilters.GaussianBlur.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tmds.DBus;

namespace Ready2Play.BitmapFilters.GaussianBlur
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ported To Avalonia Bitmap by me.
    ///
    /// Original source:
    /// https://github.com/mdymel/superfastblur
    /// Based on an article of Ivan Kuckir:
    /// http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html
    /// </summary>
    public class BitmapFilterGaussianBlur : IBitmapFilterGaussianBlur
    {
        private int[] _alpha;
        private int[] _red;
        private int[] _green;
        private int[] _blue;

        private int _width;
        private int _height;

        private Vector _dpi;

        private readonly ParallelOptions _pOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 };

        public void CreateFrom(string filePath)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public unsafe void CreateFrom(IBitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var writeableBitmap = WriteableBitmap.Decode(memoryStream);
                using var lockedBitmap = writeableBitmap.Lock();

                int* bmpPtr = (int*)lockedBitmap.Address;
                _width = writeableBitmap.PixelSize.Width;
                _height = writeableBitmap.PixelSize.Height;
                _dpi = writeableBitmap.Dpi;

                _alpha = new int[_width * _height];
                _red = new int[_width * _height];
                _green = new int[_width * _height];
                _blue = new int[_width * _height];

                Parallel.For(0, _width * _height, _pOptions, (i, parallelLoopState) =>
                {
                    _alpha[i] = (int)((*(bmpPtr + i) & 0xff000000) >> 24);
                    _red[i] = (*(bmpPtr + i) & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                    _green[i] = (*(bmpPtr + i) & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                    _blue[i] = *(bmpPtr + i) & 0x0000ff;
                });
            }
        }

        public IBitmap Process(IBitmapFilterGaussianBlurParameter parameter)
        {
            var newAlpha = new int[_width * _height];
            var newRed = new int[_width * _height];
            var newGreen = new int[_width * _height];
            var newBlue = new int[_width * _height];
            var dest = new int[_width * _height];

            Parallel.Invoke(
                () => gaussBlur_4(_alpha, newAlpha, parameter.Radius),
                () => gaussBlur_4(_red, newRed, parameter.Radius),
                () => gaussBlur_4(_green, newGreen, parameter.Radius),
                () => gaussBlur_4(_blue, newBlue, parameter.Radius));

            Parallel.For(0, dest.Length, _pOptions, i =>
            {
                //Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 255), 0)
                if (newAlpha[i] > 255) newAlpha[i] = 255;
                if (newRed[i] > 255) newRed[i] = 255;
                if (newGreen[i] > 255) newGreen[i] = 255;
                if (newBlue[i] > 255) newBlue[i] = 255;

                if (newAlpha[i] < 0) newAlpha[i] = 0;
                if (newRed[i] < 0) newRed[i] = 0;
                if (newGreen[i] < 0) newGreen[i] = 0;
                if (newBlue[i] < 0) newBlue[i] = 0;

                dest[i] = (int)((uint)(newAlpha[i] << 24) | (uint)(newRed[i] << 16) | (uint)(newGreen[i] << 8) | (uint)newBlue[i]);
            });

            var size = new PixelSize(_width, _height);
            var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(size, _dpi);
            using var lockedBitmap = writeableBitmap.Lock();
            Marshal.Copy(dest, 0, lockedBitmap.Address, dest.Length);
            return writeableBitmap;
        }

        private void gaussBlur_4(int[] source, int[] dest, int r)
        {
            var bxs = boxesForGauss(r, 3);
            boxBlur_4(source, dest, _width, _height, (bxs[0] - 1) / 2);
            boxBlur_4(dest, source, _width, _height, (bxs[1] - 1) / 2);
            boxBlur_4(source, dest, _width, _height, (bxs[2] - 1) / 2);
        }

        private int[] boxesForGauss(int sigma, int n)
        {
            var wIdeal = Math.Sqrt(12 * sigma * sigma / n + 1);
            var wl = (int)Math.Floor(wIdeal);
            if (wl % 2 == 0) wl--;
            var wu = wl + 2;

            var mIdeal = (double)(12 * sigma * sigma - n * wl * wl - 4 * n * wl - 3 * n) / (-4 * wl - 4);
            var m = Math.Round(mIdeal);

            var sizes = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) sizes.Add(i < m ? wl : wu);
            return sizes.ToArray();
        }

        private void boxBlur_4(int[] source, int[] dest, int w, int h, int r)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) dest[i] = source[i];
            boxBlurH_4(dest, source, w, h, r);
            boxBlurT_4(source, dest, w, h, r);
        }

        private void boxBlurH_4(int[] source, int[] dest, int w, int h, int r)
        {
            var iar = (double)1 / (r + r + 1);
            Parallel.For(0, h, _pOptions, i =>
            {
                var ti = i * w;
                var li = ti;
                var ri = ti + r;
                var fv = source[ti];
                var lv = source[ti + w - 1];
                var val = (r + 1) * fv;
                for (var j = 0; j < r; j++) val += source[ti + j];
                for (var j = 0; j <= r; j++)
                {
                    val += source[ri++] - fv;
                    dest[ti++] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                }
                for (var j = r + 1; j < w - r; j++)
                {
                    val += source[ri++] - dest[li++];
                    dest[ti++] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                }
                for (var j = w - r; j < w; j++)
                {
                    val += lv - source[li++];
                    dest[ti++] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                }
            });
        }

        private void boxBlurT_4(int[] source, int[] dest, int w, int h, int r)
        {
            var iar = (double)1 / (r + r + 1);
            Parallel.For(0, w, _pOptions, i =>
            {
                var ti = i;
                var li = ti;
                var ri = ti + r * w;
                var fv = source[ti];
                var lv = source[ti + w * (h - 1)];
                var val = (r + 1) * fv;
                for (var j = 0; j < r; j++) val += source[ti + j * w];
                for (var j = 0; j <= r; j++)
                {
                    val += source[ri] - fv;
                    dest[ti] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                    ri += w;
                    ti += w;
                }
                for (var j = r + 1; j < h - r; j++)
                {
                    val += source[ri] - source[li];
                    dest[ti] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                    li += w;
                    ri += w;
                    ti += w;
                }
                for (var j = h - r; j < h; j++)
                {
                    val += lv - source[li];
                    dest[ti] = (int)Math.Round(val * iar);
                    li += w;
                    ti += w;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

More:

```cs
// TODO TEST UpdateLines in parallel - Is it OK ?
/*var bench = SimpleBench.Start();*/
//      System.NullReferenceException
//HResult = 0x80004003
//Message = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
//Source = Avalonia.Base
//Arborescence des appels de procédure:
//      à Avalonia.Utilities.WeakHashList`1.GetAlive(Func`1 factory)
// à Avalonia.Utilities.WeakEvent`2.Subscription.OnEvent(Object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs)
// à Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcherLineDetails.set_IsRunning(Boolean value) dans E:\Devel\Ready2Play.NET6\Ready2Play\Ready2PlayGamesLibrary\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservablePropertyGenerator\Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcherLineDetails.g.cs :ligne 140
//        System.AggregateException
//        HResult = 0x80131500
//  Message = One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Entry point was not found.) (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Entry point was not found.) (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
//  Source = System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel
//  Arborescence des appels de procédure:
//        à System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Run[TState](ReplicatableUserAction`1 action, ParallelOptions options, Boolean stopOnFirstFailure)
//   à System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource, TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
//-- - Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent ---
//   à System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ThrowSingleCancellationExceptionOrOtherException(ICollection exceptions, CancellationToken cancelToken, Exception otherException)
//   à System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource, TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
//   à System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource, TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
//   à System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
//   à Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcher.RefreshLoadedLines() dans E:\Devel\Ready2Play.NET6\Ready2Play\Ready2PlayGamesLibrary\ProcessWatcher\ProcessWatcher.cs :ligne 286
//   à Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcher.<> c__DisplayClass18_0.< RefreshLoadedLines > b__3(Object stateInfo) dans E:\Devel\Ready2Play.NET6\Ready2Play\Ready2PlayGamesLibrary\ProcessWatcher\ProcessWatcher.cs :ligne 283
//   à System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.<> c.<.cctor > b__27_0(Object state)
//   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

//  Cette exception a été levée à l'origine dans cette pile des appels : 
//    [Code externe]
//    Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcherLineDetails.IsRunning.set(bool) dans Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcherLineDetails.g.cs
//    Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.ProcessWatcher.RefreshLoadedLines.AnonymousMethod__2(Ready2PlayGamesLibrary.ProcessWatcher.Interfaces.IProcessWatcherLineDetails) dans ProcessWatcher.cs
//    [Code externe]

//Exception interne 1 :
//NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

//Parallel.ForEach<IProcessWatcherLineDetails>(AllLinesDetails, _pOptions, (ld) =>
//        {
//            // Check if we know a process by this name
//             ld.IsRunning = false;

//            // In this case EnsureIsRightProcess can be stripped down to gain performance
//            var p = correspondingProcesses.FirstOrDefault(p => EnsureIsRightProcess(p, lineDetailsExecutableList, ld.ExecutableFullName));
//            if (p is not null)
//            {
//                ld.Process = p;
//                ld.IsRunning = !ld.HasExited || ld.Responding;
//            }

//            // Manage game state
//            if (ld.Parent.Parent is IGame game)
//{
//    var oldState = game.State;

//    // Killing an application makes this state prioritized as it's being controlled in the lineDetail itself
//    var newState = GameState.Killing;
//    if (!ld.Parent.IsOneKilling)
//        newState = ld.Parent.IsOneRunning ? GameState.Running : (!ld.IsRunning && oldState != GameState.Loading) ? GameState.Available : oldState;

//    if (oldState != newState)
//    {
//        ((IWritableGameState)game).WriteState = newState;
//    }
//}
//        });
```

Ok, I have commented those lines in my code to check later. But that the same thing. Am I misunderstanding Parallel.For ? Because if I replace it by a simple for each it works nice.

Comment: Are you sure the bitmap uses 32 bits per pixel? You're not checking the image format anywhere.

Comment: Yes it's a JPG File format handled by the Bitmap Class, the thing that  don't understand, it's why it happens "randomly". All the Bitmaps are JPG or PNG. PS: The Bitmap Class I use is from Avalonia.

Comment: JPEG notoriously is a 24bpp image format, no alpha.  Maybe a magic Bitmap class can make it 32bpp, but the exception says it didn't.  You can't assume it is okay when you don't get an AVE.

Comment: When you manipulate the bitmap data, the first thing you do is to copy your source image to a 32bit ARGB / BGRA image. When you do that, the bitmap data is aligned to a 4 bytes boundary, necessary for the processing, so you also can skip scanline bounds checks

Comment: I'am facing the same issue with another Parallel, which don't  use Bitmap. So there is another problem I can't see. See Edit.